# Authencating users between Android and PHP Webservice

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, authentication

I'm creating a simple android application, it requires some details to stored and retrieved from a web service coded in php. I have planned to create PHP script like `www.mycoolservice.com/domagic.php` Android App will request the script some details via `HTTP POST` and the script will send the data  using json encoding.

My question is about authentication and security

Which is the best way to authenticate a user with the server,should i send the username and password with every `HTTP POST`(encrypted)?

Also if there are large number of users using the same script at a time,will there be some concurrency and efficiency issues?

I'm just a beginner to web services, please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Often you have a authentication api that gives a time limited token as return value. Then you set this token in the header of other calls to the backend.

POST call to www.mycoolservice.com/authenticate.php with JSON

```
{
    "u": <user>,
    "p": <password
}
```

responds with

```
{
    "t": <token>
}
```

Calls to your www.mycoolservice.com/domagic.php with header "Token: "

Comment: can you give an example of the authentication api?

Comment: So if an intruder gets hold of this token,can't the intruder send bogus requests.Is this token encrypted?

Comment: Well yes, but that is also true for the user/password combination. The token has the nice feature of being time restricted and revocable. If you are worried about getting skimmed on credentials use https and a real SSL certificate for the host.

Comment: Is this token encrypted or is it send in plain text?

Answer (score 1):

*To add on [mach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233048/mach), who was faster than me:*

I lately read this multi-part tutorial about a REST PHP Application:

[Part 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/) and [Part 2](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/) (The last one is not yet there)

I guess a nice way is to generate an API/Authentication-Key for every user.
With the first authentication, you send it back and every communication will include the key.
 You should use `HTTP POST` for any communication though.

Comment: Thanks Nice Tutorial.But is REST needed for simple authentication.It seems kind of complex

Comment: It is not needed. It's just to show you, how the authentication key could be used. You've got to try and bring that now into your PHP-Webservice.

Comment: What im following is this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ I want to add the ability to authenticate users ie:identify the user.Should i use REST with it,or is there some easy way around

Comment: Well, the tutorial shows you, how you can generate the JSON responses. If you want to use a authentication key you just add a function to generate one for every user. The key is then added to the response JSON. In the webapplication you use that key for the POSTS that require the authentication.

Comment: Like first the user logins by entering username and password(in android).So i should send it to the server(encrypted) right?And How does the key generation process work?

Comment: Just find the method generateApiKey here [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/#highlighter_323348). You might want to use it or you need to find some other unique and secure way to generate a key. I can't really help you that much, because I didn't work with PHP since I finished my training.

Comment: And to the question about the encrypted login credentials: It could help you, if you encrypt them. But remember, that client-side encryption is never secure enough. Decide by yourself. There are some questions you'll never get an answer for.